# How to add (sub)sections to a bibliography which is using natbib?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I'm working on my dissertation in History (that's the work which constitutes part of the French master's degree). I've made a bibliography with natbib because I wanted to create the format manually (without using @book aso.) with \bibitem.

But I can't add some sections to my bibliography and it's a problem because the division is rigorous in History (Sources, General books, Specialised books, aso.).

In my mind, I could have something similar to that:

```
\begin{thebibliography}

\section*{Sources}
    \bibitem[1] P. \textsc{CHARRON} & J.-B. \textsc{JEANGENE VILMER}, \emph{Les Opérations d’influence chinoises. Un moment machiavélien}, rapport de l’Institut de recherche stratégique de l’École militaire (IRSEM), Paris, ministère des Armées, septembre 2021.

\section*{Ouvrages généraux} ... \end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se

Comment: You need to supply an argument to the environment, like `\begin{thebibliography}{1}`. I don't know what the argument does.

Comment: Use `\&` to print a `&`, and format the bibitem with data in `[...]` and a key (in `{...}`): `\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\section*{Sources}
    \bibitem[Charron et Vilmer (2021)]{cv2021} P. \textsc{CHARRON} \& J.-B. \textsc{JEANGENE VILMER}, \emph{Les Opérations d’influence chinoises. Un moment machiavélien}, rapport de l’Institut de recherche stratégique de l’École militaire (IRSEM), Paris, ministère des Armées, septembre 2021.
\section*{Ouvrages généraux} ... 
\end{thebibliography}`